# where is the wrong of parsing this xml file

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

This is my xml file:

```
<Attributes>
    <Attribute>
        <name>action</name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <name>country</name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <name>city</name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <name>location</name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <name>ad_title</name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <name>posting_date</name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <name>bedrooms</name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <name>bathrooms</name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <name>type</name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <name>size</name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <name>property_referene</name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <name>price</name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <name>price_sqft</name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <name>building</name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <name>amenities</name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <name>description</name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <name>trade_name</name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <name>ded_licence_number</name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <name>rera_registration_number</name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <name>phone</name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <name>ad_images</name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <name>payment_type</name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <name>furnished</name>
    </Attribute>

</Attributes>
```

and I have this class

```
from lxml import etree
from pprint import pprint
class defaultAttributeParser():
    def __init__(self, defaultAttributeFile):
        self.doc=etree.parse(defaultAttributeFile)

    def getDefaultAttributes(self):
        attributesDict = list()
        attributes = self.doc.findall('Attributes/Attribute')
        print(attributes)
        for attribute in attributes:
            print("asfasfd")
            attributesDict.append(attribute.find('name').text)
        return attributesDict

a = defaultAttributeParser('Apartments.xml')
pprint(len(a.getDefaultAttributes()))
```

I keep getting that the number of getDefaultAttributes is zero even though as you see, there are too many attributes, what wrong did i do please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your sample document:

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> et = lxml.etree.parse('test.xml')
>>> et.xpath('Attributes')
[]
>>> et.xpath('/Attributes')
[<Element Attributes at 0x10a55c7a0>]
```

...and, well, thus is the answer: You need to anchor your queries.

```
>>> et.xpath('/Attributes/Attribute')
```

...returns all the `Attribute` elements.